SQL71501: User: [user1] has an unresolved reference to Login [user1]
SQL Server DB Projects - when created generates the SQL Users scripts, which aren't associated with any SQL Logins but only to DB, without the condition 'WITHOUT LOGIN' and so leading Build error as below,

SQL71501: User: [user1] has an unresolved reference to Login [user1].

Took some days to find this.
Is there any settings we can adopt while Importing DB for creating SQL Server DB Project to include accurate Create SQL Users scripts, either with VS / ADS?

Since the normal logins are created in the master db, you may need to transfer it separately. MS provided a script for doing so https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances

Yes, I got it for transferring SQL logins.   But similarly, is there any standard script to create SQL Users accurately like whether they are associated with logins or not. their permissions against SQL Objects ? Still if such feature is added to SQL Server DBProjects itself, that would be great.
